# How can I programmatically replicate the editmode set to EditOnKeystrokeOrF2 behavior of a datagridview?

Tags: c#, datagridview

I use Visual C# with Windows Forms.

I need to have a DatagridView **Unbounded**, with editmode set to EditOnKeystrokeOrF2 and AllowUsersToAddRows to True (defaults) in case the user type something.

But also I need to programmatically replicate the same behavior: "Same as when you start to type something a small icon (a pencil) appears at the left side of the row, and a new row is inserted at the end of the dgv."

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Found the solution:

Instead of adding a new row, i just tell the datagrid that the cell is dirty, and voilá: it enters in edit mode, the small pencil appears and a new uncommitted row appears under it ! :)

```
this.dataGridViewModificadaDetalle.NotifyCurrentCellDirty(true);
```